# How can I embed meteor autoform or form in external page?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have created a feedback form and I need to embed that into external 
webpage when the user submit feedback that record has to be store on my application db. is it possible ?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can embed one page in another with iframe: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp